# How to stop Hadoop cat: Unable to write to output stream automatically when run loop in shell?

Tags: hadoop

I want to write a loop by shell, and do 'hadoop fs -cat' command, but when it finished , it will show 'cat: Unable to write to output stream', so that it cann't go to next step in loop. and I need to using ctrl+c to stop it by manually. so how to stop Hadoop cat: Unable to write to output stream automatically when run loop in shell?

and shell is below:

```
 for i in {00..23}; do
     echo "$i";
     mkdir $i
     cd $i
     hadoop fs -cat hdfs://xxxx/20180816/$i/*.gz | zcat | head -60000 > tmp1
     cd -
 done
```

Comment: Are you trying to search for something in those files?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in {1..2}  
do  
echo "$i" 
mkdir $i  
cd $i  
hadoop fs -get /user/sandeep1/${i}.gz  
gunzip -f ${i}.gz  
rm ${i}.gz  
hadoop fs -rm -r /user/sandeep1/${i}  
hadoop fs -mkdir /user/sandeep1/${i}  
hadoop fs -put * /user/sandeep1/${i}  
hadoop fs -cat /user/sandeep1/${i}/* | head -n 1 > tmp1.txt  
cd ..  
done
```

Comment: hi, but file is *.gz